# How to run Windows command which require administrator rights in python?

Tags: python, windows

I am building a tool which needs to modify the time on Windows.
I don’t what to use any 3rd library, So here is the Windows command I need to run

```
os.system('time xxxx')
```

If in general case I just need to open cmd as administrator it simple as that.

But in my case I put the python file which is `bsd.pyw` to the `C:\Users\${username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` which mean that python script will run when Windows starts.

So I am wondering is there a way to make that `bsd.pyw` python script run as administrator when Windows starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to run your Python script with admin privileges. I do not think it is possible to escalate to admin privilege without user intervention, directly in any script that started with non-admin; otherwise it is like a security exploit that circumvents UAC (user access control).

I would use [Task Scheduler](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/) instead of Startup folder. You can schedule your task to run when your user logs in. When you create a task, under "Security options" you can choose "Run with highest privileges".

(Sorry, I do not have a Windows machine at my hand but you can follow the link, and it contains a screenshot that explains the dialogue.)